# How to reload a python package? TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python, class, dependencies, reload, super

After reloading a branch module I just updated, I have this error : `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type` ,  until I reload the dependant modules in the correct order.

I have this kind of dependencies:

```
weird
  |_  __init__.py
  |_  A.py
  |_  B.py
  |_  C.py
```

A.py:

```
import B
```

B.py:

```
import C
class Baleze(C.WeshGros):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Baleze, self).__init__()
```

C.py:

```
class WeshGros(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WeshGros, self).__init__()
        print('nothing')
```

`>>>import A`

now replace `print('nothing')` with `print('reallyNothing')` in C.py

`>>>reload(C)`

`>>>reload(A)`

`TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

I don't want to manually reload B as my tree dependencie is big. What's the best practice to solve this ?

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you have ```super(WheshGros, self).__init__()``` in C.py?

Comment: Reloading Python modules will almost always produce problems like this, watch this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlgbPLvBs30

Comment: @ewong, Yeah it sounds stupid, but in my case I inherit from another class, I did put "object" here for the example :)

Comment: @IainShelvington, thanks a lot for the link, this conf is mindblowing ! I watched it 3 times to understand fully but it's so interesting! If you have any other like this I take ! :D Thanks again!!